# Javascript - ChartJS Trying to change the borderColor and the fill color for negative numbers

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am currently creating a LineChart with ChartJs that represents someone's profits. These can be positive or negative.

I want the lines above zero to be green and the lines below to be red. Also, the background must be red when the values are negative.
I have already seen solutions with previous versions of ChartJS on Stackoverflow, however I think with this new version there may be a more elegant version to solve this problem.

I am using version `4.2.0` of `chartJs`.

Here is what I have done so far following the documentation :

```
const lineChartData = {
    labels: [
      '01/22',
      '02/22',
      '03/22',
      '04/22',
      '05/22',
      '06/22',
      '07/22',
      '08/22',
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Profit',
        data: [2.4, 2.6, 2.23, 1.2, -2.2, -3.6, -1, 0.2],
        borderColor: '#0B9564',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        borderJoinStyle: 'bevel',
        fill: {
          target: 'origin',
          above: 'rgba(11, 149, 100, 0.08)',
          below: 'rgba(218, 96, 96, 0.08)',
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```

And here is the actual result:

[image: actual code preview]

Finally, here is a preview of what I would like it to look like. This is a mock-up, so it's not quite accurate.
[image: mockup image]

Do you have any idea how I could reproduce this? It doesn't seem to me that in the documentation this problem is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the Box you won't be able to do this, the best would be something like in the example below (using [the segementation styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/segments.html), and a *[linear color gradient](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html)*).

If you really need this exact look, you could check if someone has created a plugin, or create your own plugin *(or inline plugin)*, that would override the normal rendering. ([link to plugin documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html)).

**Here a demo, how I would do this:**
*(based on the configuration, you posted)*

```js
const lineChartData = {
    labels: [
      '01/22',
      '02/22',
      '03/22',
      '04/22',
      '05/22',
      '06/22',
      '07/22',
      '08/22',
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Profit',
        data: [2.4, 2.6, 2.23, 1.2, -2.2, -3.6, -1, 0.2],
        borderColor: '#0B9564',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        borderJoinStyle: 'bevel',
        fill: {
            value: -25,
            above: 'rgba(11, 149, 100, 0.08)'
        },
        segment: {
            borderColor: ctx => segmentColor(ctx, '#0B9564', 'red')
        }
      },
    ],
  };
  
function segmentColor(ctx, color1, color2){
    if(ctx.p0.parsed.y < 0 && ctx.p1.parsed.y < 0 ) {
        return color2;
    } else if (ctx.p0.parsed.y < 0){
        var gradient = myChart.ctx.createLinearGradient(ctx.p0.x, ctx.p0.y, ctx.p1.x, ctx.p1.y);
        gradient.addColorStop(.5, color2);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, color1);  
        return gradient
    } else if (ctx.p1.parsed.y < 0){
        var gradient = myChart.ctx.createLinearGradient(ctx.p1.x, ctx.p1.y, ctx.p0.x, ctx.p0.y);
        gradient.addColorStop(.5, color2);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, color1);   
        return gradient
    }
    return color1
}

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                labels: {
                    usePointStyle: true,
                },
            }
        },
    }
};

var myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  

<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```